# Can linux samba server (smbd) provide to (Windows) clients if a file is symlink (or hardlink or btrfs reflink)?

Tags: linux, samba, symbolic-link

I have a NAS with Debian. Disk in NAS is btrfs. Service which serves files is samba server (smbd).

I have a Windows client with an external NTFS disk.

I want to synchronize NAS disk with external disk via FreeFileSync program on samba protocol.

Linux samba server does not provide to Windows clients if a file is a symlink or hardlink or btrfs reflink.

Is there an option on smbd.conf which can provide such info to Windows clients?
At least for symlinks.

What I want, is when FreeFileSync found a symlink to source btrfs/samba, create the same symlink to target NTFS/local and not copy as normal file.

FreeFileSync can do this but samba does not provide if a file is normal or symlink (and symlink target).

Comment: Which info? That the symlink wasn't made available? The cause might be the lack of permissions to access the symlink target.

Comment: Note: while a symlink is different than what it points to, a hardlinked copy and its "original" are equivalent. Every regular file is a hardlink; the link count is what counts and it may be one or more. Do you want Windows to know if the count is more than one then? With btrfs reflinks it's yet different: some part of a file may be shared with several other files (and even with other fragment(s) of this very file, I think); at the same time some other part may be unique. Now what?

Comment: smbd won't automatically let clients follow symlinks by default, but you can configure it to do so in smb.conf. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137192

Comment: @harrymc FreeFileSync understands that a file in external NTFS disk is symlink but it does not understand that a file in NAS/smbd is symlink. It understands that it is a normal file and it has access to it.

Comment: @FrankThomas the problem is not following symlinks but provide information to client that this file is a symlink.

Comment: The only samba parameter which is vaguely relevant is "follow symlinks" but its effect is not what you want: "Setting this parameter to no prevents any file or directory that is a symbolic link from being followed (the user will get an error)." There is no parameter for treating symlinks as files.